# R - statsmodel - 'ARIMAResults' object has no attribute "'endog'" - python

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, arima

So I am attempting to do some time series analysis with the statsmodel package in python. I have some code that was given to me in a class - but it doesn't work! I've narrowed down the error to the function below, but am getting a strange error metric that I can't solve.

```
def model_ARIMA_2(ts, order):
    from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
    from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMAResults    
    model = ARIMA(ts, order = order)
    model_fit = model.fit(disp=0, method='mle', trend='nc')
    BIC = ARIMAResults(model_fit, order).bic
    print('Testing model of order: ' + str(order) + ' with BIC = ' + str(BIC))
    return(BIC, order, model_fit)

order = (1,1,1)
model_ARIMA_2(decomp.resid[6:-6], order)
```

And I get the error: AttributeError: 'ARIMAResults' object has no attribute 'endog'

My data looks like:

[image]

I've tried searching this online and haven't found anything helpful. Does anyone know why this error is cropping up and what the solution may be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the error occurs when you are trying to extract the BIC.

When you fit an ARIMA model, in your case `model_fit = model.fit(disp=0, method='mle', trend='nc')`, Statsmodels returns an ARIMAResults object (see the [documentation for the fit method](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.fit.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.fit)). So you are attempting to create an ARIMAResults object from an ARIMAResults object, which is causing your error.

You should be able get the BIC directly from the object returned when you fit the model (i.e. `BIC = model_fit.bic`) as well as all other model fitting statsmodels reports.

It will be useful to become familiar with the methods and attributes of ARIMAResults objects which can be found [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults).

Best of luck!